# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.ngtsc(-998002)

Tags: angular

I receive the error **can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'**  on my angular app, when i add a `[(ngModel)]="email"`.

I already added `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` in the `app.module.ts` but still doen't work, here is my code on sandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-ives-czxn2?file=/src/app/modules/login/components/login-form/login-form.component.html

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things

1. Your login-form.component is being declared in login.module.ts, which also needs the import for forms module
2. Once you do that though, there is a new error saying the input needs a name on it. So just add name="email" as well.

**login.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { LoginComponent } from "./pages/login/login.component";
import { LoginFormComponent } from "./components/login-form/login-form.component";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent, LoginFormComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule]
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

**login-form.component.html**

```
<h1 class="Login-title">Connexion</h1>

<form>
  <input id="email" type="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks you for you answer for the first step it's ok i added forms module in the login.modules.ts but for the second step sorry i don't understand : i receive Unexpected module 'FormsModule' declared by the module 'LoginModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation (https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-sky-g2cbm?file=/src/app/modules/login/login.module.ts:42-87)

Comment: I updated my answer, hopefully that's a little more clear.

Comment: Yes you solution solved my problem ! thanks you